# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in chrome console

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

I am trying to make an Ajax call to hit a webservice and get the response.But getting uncaught syntaxerror:unexpected token < in google chrome console.
Here's my Ajax Request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:"http://10.10.1.5:8089/axis2/services/cmtlpmservice/getAllMonitors",
       dataType:"jsonp",
       jsonpCallback:"callback",
       type:"GET",
       success:function(response){
           console.log(response);
       }
    });
});
```

The Request header  is as follows:

Request URL:http://10.10.1.5:8089/axis2/services/cmtlpmservice  /getAllMonitors?callback=callback&_=1487912464838
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:10.10.1.5:8089

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:10.10.1.5:8089
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36

The Response Header as follows:

Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 24 Feb 2017 05:01:05 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 10:00:00 EST
Pragma:No-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1

The Response looks like :

```
<ns:getAllMonitorsResponse xmlns:ns="ws.core.dorado.com">
 <ns:return> 
{
    "monitors": [{
        "id": "com.dorado.broadscope.monitor.Monitor::R‌​GNEXGvol54w2a#_1.3.6‌​.1.4.1.20138.800.20.‌​12.1.9.1",
        "maxAttrNa‌​me": "ifTemperatureVa‌​lue Max",
        "name": "ifTemperatureValue",
        "minAttrName": "ifTemperatur‌​eValue Min",
        "maxAttrId": "com.dorado.broadscope.monitor.Monitor::RGN‌​EXGvol54w2a#_1.3.6.1‌​.4.1.20138.800.20.12‌​.1.9.1Max",
        "minAttrI‌​d": "com.dorado.broad‌​scope.monitor.Monito‌​r::RGNEXGvol54w2a#_1‌​.3.6.1.4.1.20138.800‌​.20.12.1.9.1Min"
    }]
}

 </ns:return> 
</ns:getAllMonitorsResponse>
```

Comment: I suspect your webservice isn't returning a valid JSON response.

Comment: This is how my response looks like :<ns:getAllMonitorsResponse xmlns:ns="http://ws.core.dorado.com">
<ns:return>
{"monitors":[{"id":"com.dorado.broadscope.monitor.Monitor::RGNEXGvol54w2a#_1.3.6.1.4.1.20138.800.20.12.1.9.1","maxAttrName":"ifTemperatureValue Max","name":"ifTemperatureValue","minAttrName":"ifTemperatureValue Min","maxAttrId":"com.dorado.broadscope.monitor.Monitor::RGNEXGvol54w2a#_1.3.6.1.4.1.20138.800.20.12.1.9.1Max","minAttrId":"com.dorado.broadscope.monitor.Monitor::RGNEXGvol54w2a#_1.3.6.1.4.1.20138.800.20.12.1.9.1Min"}]}
</ns:return>
</ns:getAllMonitorsResponse>

Comment: What does the response *body* look like? You've only shown the header.

Comment: I'm with @scoota269 - your server is responding most likely with a regular webpage

Comment: @PallaviSarawgi not only is that not JSON, it's not JSONP either (which you would need for your request for jsonp to work)

Comment: Also, please put the response body as an update to your question, not a comment.

Comment: I am doing this for the first time. Calling a webservice through javascript.

Comment: the javascript (may be) ok ... it's the server that you are doing wrong ... that's where you need help

Comment: Response has xml tags, i am interested in data under monitors which is in json format.

Comment: then don't write the client side as expecting JSONP ... it's XML ... of course, then you'll have CORS issues

Comment: Exactly...I had CORS issues when using xml and i read somewhere that jsonp resolves them. Am a beginner here.

Comment: ahhh, you thought JSONP bypasses CORS without any rewrite of the server side code - CORS would be useless if a client could do that!!! No, either way, the server needs to be rewritten to either send JSONP, or to send CORS headers so you can use your "orignal code"

Comment: How do we update the server to send CORS headers?

Answer (score 0):

Due to some error in **getAllMonitors** it returns whole html page instade of json deta in **response**. your controller is culpit insted of your ajax.